# Bootstrap fileinput plugin json error

Tags: php

By the click of the delete button, I receive this error. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. Can someone help me resolve it as all efforts to resolve it have proved futile.

Here's a screenshot of the error.

[json error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDgrN.png)

And here's the screenshot of my directory structure.
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icrk2.png)

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Bootstrap File Upload</title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>



    <input id="files" name="images[]" type="file" multiple=true class="file-loading">
    </body>
    <?php   
    $directory = "images_/";      
    $images = glob($directory . "*.*");
    ?>

    <script>
    $("#files").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "upload.php", 
    uploadAsync: false,
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 20,
    showUpload: false, 
    showRemove: false,
    initialPreview: [
    <?php foreach($images as $image){?>
        "<img src='<?php echo $image; ?>' height='120px' class='file-preview-image'>",
    <?php } ?>],
    initialPreviewConfig: [<?php foreach($images as $image){ $infoImages=explode("/",$image);?>
    {caption: "<?php echo $infoImages[1];?>",  height: "120px", url: "delete.php", key:"<?php echo $infoImages[1];?>"},
    <?php } ?>]
    }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {

    $("#files").fileinput("upload");

    });

    </script>
</html>
```

Here's my upload.php

```
<?php 
$enclosedFolder="images_/";
// Count sent by plugin
$Images =count(isset($_FILES['images']['name'])?$_FILES['images']['name']:0);
$infoImagesUploaded = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $Images; $i++) {
    // The name and the temporary file name we're gonna attach
    $nameFile=isset($_FILES['images']['name'][$i])?$_FILES['images']['name'][$i]:null;
    $nameTemp=isset($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i])?$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i]:null;

    $pathFile=$enclosedFolder.$nameFile;

    move_uploaded_file($nameTemp,$pathFile);

    $infoImagesUploaded[$i]=array("caption"=>"$nameFile","height"=>"120px","url"=>"delete.php","key"=>$nameFile);
    $ImagesUploaded[$i]="<img  height='120px'  src='$pathFile' class='file-preview-image'>";
    }
$arr = array("file_id"=>0,"overwriteInitial"=>true,"initialPreviewConfig"=>$infoImagesUploaded,
             "initialPreview"=>$ImagesUploaded);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

And here's my delete.php

```
<?php 
$enclosedFolder="images_/";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="DELETE"){
            parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$dataDELETE);
            $key= $dataDELETE['key'];
            unlink($enclosedFolder.$key);

            echo 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [Github](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/issues/127):

> Its an error on your server code returning an invalid json format for
>   your upload response. Debug it with firebug or javascript console and
>   resolve to return a right JSON format. You must return a RIGHT JSON
>   response from your AJAX (even if you do not have anything... you must
>   at least return an empty JSON object like {}).

Comment: but this is the entire code. I can't figure out where the error is. Can u?

Comment: The JSON data you send to the fileinput function.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP file, I'm feedback empty JSON to Ajax

return "{}";

or

echo "{}";